# AWK rearranging file to create new values in existing column

Tags: awk

I have the following file called an.txt:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{print $0}' an.txt | head -n 4

Bank Fee    Monthly A/C Fee             -8.50   31/03/2021      
Eft-Pos Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    210331123119    -250.00 31/03/2021      
Payment Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  Labour  -131.60 31/03/2021      
Bill Payment    Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    I1600   50.00   31/03/2021
```

I have reconfigured the file with the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1{split($7,a,"/") ; print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]"\t"$6"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4}' an.txt | head -n 4

2021-03-31  -8.50   Monthly A/C Fee     
2021-03-31  -250.00 Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C
2021-03-31  -131.60 Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315
2021-03-31  50.00   Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent
```

What I would like to achieve is that the remaining column ($5) is used to print az at the same time in the one command. So what I have tried is the following unsucessful command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1{split($7,a,"/") ; print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]"\t"$6"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5="az"}' an.txt | head -n 4

awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                 ^ syntax error
```

How can I write the command so I achieve the following output?

Desired output:

```
2021-03-31  -8.50   Monthly A/C Fee az      
2021-03-31  -250.00 Rutherford & Bond   4835********    8848   C    az
2021-03-31  -131.60 Avery Johnson   Avery Johnso    592315  az
2021-03-31  50.00   Collins Tf  127 Driver  Crescent    az
```

Comment: Your final column, $5, does not need assigning to. Remove the `$5=`.

Comment: Thanks James that works. I new it had to be something really stupid.

Comment: It's not obvious, that's all.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson - why don't you go ahead and write up an answer so it can be selected and this question bumped off the active queue. A quick one paragraph expanding (slightly) on your comment above will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial attempt at a "Now that I've got this kinda working, I want to make it better" solution is subtly incorrect.

Here is what Christian wrote (line breaks and spaces inserted to improve clarity):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    NR>1 {
        split($7,a,"/") ;
        print a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1] "\t" $6 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5="az"
    }' an.txt | head -n 4
```

The important part is the print statement, where the final argument to the `print()` function is

```
$5="az"
```

The *intent* is clear - assign the string `az` to the fifth column. That has no effect on the print statement, however, because it is implicitly terminating the print statement early.

To achieve the stated goal of adding the string `az` at the end of every line, the print statement just needs to print that, rather than perform an assignment. Therefore the print statement needs to be

```
print a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1] "\t" $6 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" az
```

and my personal preference is to wrap the arguments in parentheses to ensure that we are very clear that they are args, so I would write

```
print(a[3] "-" a[2] "-" a[1] "\t" $6 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" az)
```

Comment: awsome. Thanks for the detailed explaination